# Hi I want a SQL recursive query so that the result of the query need to applied back into the same query until the query result's become zero

Tags: sql, recursive-query, sql-query-store

For example I have the following table

```
(ID,    Employee_Name,  Employee_Guide, Employee_Salary)
(101,   John,   Jacob,  1000)
(102,   Jeny,   Josh,   1000)
(103,   Josh,   Jack,   1000)
(104,James, Jamel,  1000)
(105,   Jamel,  Jaxon,  1000)
```

If I query search for John and Jeny. the result need to be like

```
(ID,    Employee_Name,  Employee_Guide, Employee_Salary)
(101,   John,   Jacob,  1000)
(102,   Jeny,   Josh,   1000)
(103,   Josh,   Jack,   1000)
```

as Josh is a Guide and also a Employee.

Can any one help me here. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think it should be recursive:

```
select * 
from employees 
where employee_guide in ('Josh', 'Jeny') or employee_name in ('Josh', 'Jeny')
```

Comment: But My query is about "John" and "Jeny" and expected output need to include the details of "John","Jeny","Josh"

Comment: @SamPrakashShine then simple add John to the list.. like where employee_guide in ('Josh', 'Jeny', 'John') or employee_name in ('Josh', 'Jeny', 'John')